# .loc for CategoricalIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to access the rows of a CategoricalIndex-based Pandas dataframe using .loc but I get a `TypeError`. A minimum **non** working example would be

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': rand(3), 'future_index': [22, 13, 87]})
df['future_index'] = df['future_index'].astype('category')
df = df.set_index('future_index')
```

Then, in trying to access the row corresponding to label 13 as

```
df.loc[13]
```

I get

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.category.CategoricalIndex'> with these indexers [13] of <class 'int'>
```

despite

```
13 in df.index
```

being `True`. I know I can ultimately obtain the index of 13 with

```
df.index.get_loc(13)
```

but, why is the above easier approach not working? What am I missing?

Cheers.

Comment: This looks like something that currently isn't implemented for integer based CategoricalIndices, if your categories were character/str based e.g. `'a','b','c'` then `df.loc['a']` would work. It looks like this is a limitation currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working:

```
print (df.loc[pd.CategoricalIndex([13])])
              foo
future_index     
13              2
```

But if convert to `str` as mentioned [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039400/loc-for-categoricalindex-in-pandas#comment79039304_46039400) it working nice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,3], 'future_index': [22, 13, 87]})
df['future_index'] = df['future_index'].astype(str).astype('category')
df = df.set_index('future_index')
print (df)

print (df.loc['13'])
foo    2
Name: 13, dtype: int64
```